# How to make a dataframe from a value_counts function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have the dataframe below and I want to get how many values 1,2,3,4 and 5 each columns has.

The desired output would be:

```
feature   count_of1    count_of2  count_of3  count_of4   count_of5
diamater     3             2         8           18         29
value        0             0         1            7         52
lenght       7             7         12           15        19
```

I know it is basicaly a `value_counts()` but I don´t know how to make a DataFrame in this desided format.

Important:  the example below has only 3 columns but It can be many more so don´t want to hard code the columns names.

In a Pandas DataFrame:

```
pd.DataFrame({'diameter': {0: 5,
  1: 5,
  2: 5,
  3: 4,
  4: 5,
  5: 5,
  6: 5,
  7: 5,
  8: 4,
  9: 4,
  10: 4,
  11: 5,
  12: 4,
  13: 5,
  14: 1,
  15: 5,
  16: 5,
  17: 4,
  18: 1,
  19: 5,
  20: 3,
  21: 4,
  22: 5,
  23: 5,
  24: 4,
  25: 5,
  26: 2,
  27: 5,
  28: 2,
  29: 4,
  30: 3,
  31: 5,
  32: 5,
  33: 5,
  34: 4,
  35: 5,
  36: 5,
  37: 5,
  38: 3,
  39: 4,
  40: 4,
  41: 3,
  42: 4,
  43: 5,
  44: 5,
  45: 3,
  46: 1,
  47: 5,
  48: 4,
  49: 3,
  50: 5,
  51: 3,
  52: 5,
  53: 5,
  54: 4,
  55: 4,
  56: 4,
  57: 4,
  58: 5,
  59: 3},
 'value': {0: 5,
  1: 5,
  2: 5,
  3: 5,
  4: 5,
  5: 5,
  6: 4,
  7: 5,
  8: 5,
  9: 5,
  10: 5,
  11: 5,
  12: 5,
  13: 5,
  14: 5,
  15: 5,
  16: 5,
  17: 4,
  18: 3,
  19: 5,
  20: 5,
  21: 5,
  22: 5,
  23: 5,
  24: 5,
  25: 5,
  26: 5,
  27: 5,
  28: 5,
  29: 5,
  30: 5,
  31: 5,
  32: 5,
  33: 5,
  34: 4,
  35: 5,
  36: 5,
  37: 5,
  38: 5,
  39: 5,
  40: 5,
  41: 5,
  42: 5,
  43: 4,
  44: 5,
  45: 5,
  46: 5,
  47: 4,
  48: 5,
  49: 5,
  50: 5,
  51: 4,
  52: 5,
  53: 5,
  54: 5,
  55: 5,
  56: 5,
  57: 4,
  58: 5,
  59: 5},
 'lenght': {0: 2,
  1: 2,
  2: 2,
  3: 3,
  4: 2,
  5: 5,
  6: 3,
  7: 3,
  8: 3,
  9: 3,
  10: 3,
  11: 5,
  12: 5,
  13: 3,
  14: 5,
  15: 2,
  16: 4,
  17: 2,
  18: 1,
  19: 3,
  20: 4,
  21: 4,
  22: 1,
  23: 4,
  24: 5,
  25: 5,
  26: 3,
  27: 5,
  28: 3,
  29: 3,
  30: 3,
  31: 5,
  32: 2,
  33: 3,
  34: 2,
  35: 5,
  36: 4,
  37: 5,
  38: 3,
  39: 5,
  40: 5,
  41: 3,
  42: 3,
  43: 1,
  44: 4,
  45: 3,
  46: 1,
  47: 1,
  48: 2,
  49: 3,
  50: 5,
  51: 2,
  52: 2,
  53: 1,
  54: 5,
  55: 4,
  56: 5,
  57: 2,
  58: 1,
  59: 3}})
```

​

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
(df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts)
   #.reindex(range(0, df.max().max()+1))
   .T
   .fillna(0, downcast='infer')
   .add_prefix('count_of_')
 )
```

*NB. Uncomment the `reindex` line if you want to ensure having all columns, even if all values for this number are 0.*

Output:

```
          count_of_1  count_of_2  count_of_3  count_of_4  count_of_5
diameter           3           2           8          18          29
value              0           0           1           7          52
lenght             7          12          19           7          15
```